# Can't print popup in firefox 31 when css included

Tags: javascript, html

I want to open a popup with an included css and I want to have it printable but the Firefox behaves weird. I am not sure its my fault or its a bug. There is no problem in Chrome.

```
<html>
   <head>
     <script>
     popup = function(){
        var html = "";
        html += "<html>";
        html += "<head>";
        html += '<link rel="stylesheet" href="popup_print.css">';
        html += "</head>";
        html += "<body>";
        html += '<a onclick="print()">abc</a>';
        html += "</body>";
        html += "</html>";

        var printPopup = window.open("", "PrintWindow", "width=400, height=600, scrollbars=1");
        printPopup.document.write(html);
    }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
      <a onclick="popup()">abc</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

When there is no css link I have no problems...

Comment: And what's your CSS?

Comment: tested on firefox 40 and it works as chrome @unixarmy you can test with A{color:red;} for example..

Comment: Can you check if you have any errors in console window? If yes, what error do you get?

Comment: No console errors but when I reload the page after I press the print-button the download dialogue appears

Comment: Tested on Firefox 40 portable and got the same problem.